# Is it correct that on Form 3520 you don't have to fill out the address of the foreign donor?

Tags: united-states, gift-tax, gifts

I'm receiving a gift from a foreign person and am drafting the informational return 3520 (https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/f3520--2017.pdf) to report it.

What surprises me is that in section IV, you don't appear to have to enter any details of the foreign person giving the gift, only the date, a description, and the FMV (fair market value).

Is this correct?